# C++ E0137 expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, if-statement, lvalue

I want to do the coding like enter your user name and password, and then it will tell you succeed or not.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const int USR = 201910, PSW = 765705590;
    int user, psw;
    cout << "user:";
    cin >> user;
    cout << "password:";
    cin >> psw;
    if(user == USR && psw = PSW) // 2 errors: 1. E1037 expression must be a modifiable lvalue 2. '='left operand must be l-value
    {
        cout << "welcome to US bank!";
    }
    else if (user != USR || psw != PSW)
    {
        cout << "password  or username is wrong!";
    }
}
```

I am a comer in C++, could you help me to figure out this two errors? thanks!

Comment: Change `psw = PSW` to `psw == PSW`

Answer (score 4):

> if(user == USR && psw = PSW) // 2 errors: 1. E1037 expression must be
>   a modifiable lvalue 2. '='left operand must be l-value

The error is here: `psw = PSW`

Going by the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence),

`user == USR && psw = PSW`

becomes

`((user == USR) && psw) = PSW`

Now see `((user == USR) && psw)`. What do you think the result of this expression would be? It is either `true` or `false`, which is not an lvalue.

[What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

In simple words, what are you assigning `PSW` to? It makes no sense because the LHS of that expression is not a variable.

**Solution:**

You may be surprised by these errors because you actually just wanted to compare if `psw` is equal to `PSW`, but you accidentally used that assignment operator.

Replace `psw = PSW` with `psw == PSW`.

Comment: Yeah, the question's a typo, but this is a great answer.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, now it is working now! wonderful and thank you!